# Maximum function on I.I.D random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence, uniform-distribution

Let $X_1$ , $X_2$ , $X_3$ , $X_4$ be i.i.d random variables U [$0$,$1$]

How do I find P [ $X_3$ < $X_2$ < max ($X_1$,$X_4$) ] ?

I know that this problem can be solved using the exchangeable property of i.i.d random variables. However, I tried solving this problem using the conventional integration/required region way, but my answer was coming wrong. How do I solve this problem using integration method.

For example, I tried doing this:
P [ $X_3$ < $X_2$ < max ($X_1$,$X_4$) ]

= P [ $X_3$ < $X_2$ < $X_1$ > $X_4$) ] + P [ $X_3$ < $X_2$ < $X_4$ > $X_1$ ]

= 2 $\int_{0}^{x_2} \int_{x_3}^{x_1}\int_{x_2}^{1}\int_{0}^{x_1} \,dx_4dx_1dx_2dx_3 $

Comment: You do not really need integral for this given all of them are $U [0, 1]$. In total there are $4!$ orders and you are interested in $6$ of them and hence the probability is $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: @MathLover OP already mentioned that they know this simpler approach, but wanted to reconcile it with the integral approach.

Comment: @angryavian my bad. I didn't read fully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limits of integration are not right. The limits of an integral cannot depend on dummy variables that are integrated away in inner integrals.

$$P(X_3 < X_2 < X_1 > X_4) = \int_0^1 \int_{x_3}^1 \int_{x_2}^1 \int_0^{x_1} dx_4\, dx_1 \, dx_2 \, dx_3$$

Comment: Thank you! I found out my mistakes.

Comment: @ParamChaudhry If an answer helps you, you may choose to acknowledge by upvoting and / or accepting it. You cannot upvote an answer until you have certain reputation but you can always accept an answer. If there are multiple answers to a question, you can upvote any number of answers but can accept only one of them. See here on how to accept an answer - https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer/3287#3287